# Gunicorn + Gevent + kafka python + Flask : Consumer STOPPING after idle time

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent, kafka-python

We have a Python FLASK app in which we are using Kafka Consumer and Flask app is running through Gunicorn with Gevent worker.

We spawn 3 threads for same script with some parameters and it creates 3 Kafka consumers. We don't run same script 3 times.

Once Consumer has started and is idle for few minutes the consumer exits the poll loop.
Restarting the consumer via Flask api[Curl Command] we get some records from Kafka and then after some time the consumer goes in idle state and cannot resume again.

The traffic in Kafka is less[it is not continuous], the records come after hours.

We have dockerized it and it is running in container. 
We have to hit manually the curl command[3 times for 3 threads] to start the service for each consumer.

Running in nohup python3 script.py is working perfectly/continuously i.e without Gunicorn.

Any thoughts on this?